# Trying to SELECT certain rows from TABLE where values are DISTINCT

Tags: sql, select, distinct

I am trying to return rows with DISTINCT fields, but the SELECT is of different fields. The reason behind it is because this query is between UNION'ed queries. So I need to output to match what the other queries are outputting. Hard to explain, here is an example:

```
UNION---

SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT Value1 || Value2 || Value3 as DESCRIPTION, Value4
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE Value5 = <some distinct value>)
WHERE Value6 = 1

---UNION
```

So basically I want the output to be 2 columns so that all the the UNION'ed queries will have a nice output. I guess I just don't know the syntax to make the WHERE clause use a distinct value.

Comment: Maybe you need GROUP BY instead?

Comment: What is the problem with your query?  That might help us understand how to make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not have a `value6` outside the subquery.  You would need to express this as:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Value1 || Value2 || Value3 as DESCRIPTION, Value4
      FROM TABLE
      WHERE Value5 = <some distinct value> and
            Value6 = 1
     ) t
```

I don't know if that helps with your problem, though.

As an aside, is there a style of formatting that puts `from` at the end of a line?  I see this from time to time and just don't get it.  Are their humans who actually prefer this?